# Modifying Existing JBPM Schema

Tags: jbpm

Can we modify Existing JBPM Schema or add some extra tales to the schema.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.** As long as you add additional columns or additional tables, it will be working fine. If you would like to use additional properties on entites, you should add them as process instance attributes, so they get persisted correctely and can be accessed from the process instance context at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You, you can, without any troubles.

If you want, however, to add additional properties to JBPM entities, it is preferable to create your own entities, with `@OneToOne` to the JBPM ones.

Another option is to use hibernate inheritance with `TABLE_PER_CLASS` and extend the JBPM entity you want.